# Ruby: Does paho-mqtt with QOS=1 automatically resend (re-publish) unacknowledged messages for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mqtt, paho, ruby-mqtt

I am using the `paho-mqtt` gem in ruby.
I was wondering if the gem automatically resends (re-publish) the message to the MQTT broker in case PUBACK is not received on client side for some reason, or do I have to do it manually? `QOS=1`

ex (this is me publishing with QOS=1, and not doing anything else):

```
client = PahoMqtt::Client.new

client.on_puback do
  puts "PUBACK received"
end

client.connect(@mqtt_server_ip, @mqtt_server_port)
client.publish(topic, message_payload, false, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it manually using the `on_puback` callback.
The answer is it has to be done manually :)